# how can i make blue (#007bff) rounded backgrounds of full width on hover?

Tags: html, css

I want 100% width blue rounded background on hover. I tried various ways but couldn't. Please help me to create a blue (#007bff) rounded background of border radius 10px on hover. Remember on hover it should cover the whole block not only a tag highlight.

[Codepen link to my work](https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/bGMzYmy)

```css
.sidebar{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.open.sidebar {
  display: block;
}
#mySidebar{
  transition:all 0.2s linear;
  /*transform:translateX(-250px);*/
}
#mySidebar.open{
  transform:translateX(0);
}
.sidebar-header{
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
  height: 3rem;
}
.sidebar-header .profile{
  display:  flex;
  color: #fff;
}
.profile .profile-image img{
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left:  20px;
}
.profile .profile-name{
  display: inline-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 2px 0 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.profile .profile-name i{
  margin: -2px 5px 0 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.sidebar-nav{
margin: 0;
}
.sidebar-nav ul{
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: flex-start;
list-style:none;
line-height: 30px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li{
width:100%;
color:#007bff;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a{
text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a:hover{
background:#007bff;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="https://www.directive.com/images/easyblog_shared/July_2018/7-4-18/b2ap3_large_totw_network_profile_400.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="profile-name">
                <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i><span>Umann Goswami</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--sidebar-header-->
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
             
             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
             
             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!--sidebar-->
```

Comment: what do you mean cover the whole block not only a tag highlight.? please share an image to show us what you want. because you have many spans in your list and they take some space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the background color of your anchor tag rather than the element this tag is in, so in this case the `li` (List Item). To have the full background for the link and the list item, you have to move the `:hover` over to `li`, or add a chaining rule like this:

```css
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover, .sidebar-nav ul li:hover a {
    background:#007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```css
.sidebar{
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 15.625rem;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.open.sidebar {
    display: block;
}
#mySidebar{
    transition:all 0.2s linear;
    /*transform:translateX(-250px);*/
}
#mySidebar.open{
    transform:translateX(0);
}
.sidebar-header{
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
    height: 3rem;
}
.sidebar-header .profile{
    display:  flex;
    color: #fff;
}
.profile .profile-image img{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    object-fit: fill;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left:  20px;
}
.profile .profile-name{
    display: inline-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 2px 0 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.profile .profile-name i{
    margin: -2px 5px 0 2px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.sidebar-nav{
margin: 0;
}
.sidebar-nav ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    list-style:none;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    color:#007bff;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover, .sidebar-nav ul li:hover a {
    background:#007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="profile-image">
                <img src="https://www.directive.com/images/easyblog_shared/July_2018/7-4-18/b2ap3_large_totw_network_profile_400.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="profile-name">
                <i class="fas fa-chess-pawn"></i><span>Umann Goswami</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--sidebar-header-->
    <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
             
             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>

             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
             
             <li><a href=""><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!--sidebar-->
```

Extra: Note that your list items, are slightly padded to the right. To fix this, you could add `padding: 0 15px;` where `15px` is padding left and padding right.

```css
.sidebar-nav ul {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    list-style:none;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add display: block to "a" tags